# JQuery: Check if previous sibling is first-child

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery, how do you check if an element's previous sibling is the first-child?

I have tried the following code but it does not work:

```
if( $(this).prev() === $(this).siblings(":first-child") ){
    //do something
}
```

**An example using the above `===` approach: http://jsfiddle.net/xnHfM/**

Comment: Are you asking if the element is the second child?  Would  `$(this).prev().prev().length == 0` work or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if($(this).index() === 1){ // if index is 1 it means it's for sure the second children
  // here u can grab $(this).prev(), and it's for sure the first one
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/p7sAq/

p.s. I'll try to see the perf about this solution vs .is(':first-child') => http://jsperf.com/jquery-check-previous-first-child

**edit** : see last comment, thanks @RightSaidFred :)

Comment: +1 - thanks, a clever solution, but not quite as readable as Yoshi's

Comment: Ok, I'll wait to see if you can find that before I accept @Yoshi's

Comment: Done (see the link on my answer), it seems faster with index(), although u should try with some other browsers.

Comment: Intersting results. In most browsers it is almost 50% quicker (including IE7/8) - oddly however, first-child was a little quicker in IE9.

Comment: Yea I noticed.. really weird!

Comment: Why bother with `.prev()`? You could just do `if($(this).index() === 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().find(">:first-child")[0] == $(this).prev()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be the most efficient way, but you could use [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and count the amount of previous siblings.  Here's an example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hWYJ/))...

```
<ul id="test1">
    <li>One</li> 
    <li class="two">Two</li>
</ul>
<ul id="test1">
    <li>One</li>     
    <li>Two</li>
    <li class="three">Three</li>
</ul>
<script>
alert("Test 1 is...");
alert($("#test1 .two").prevAll().length == 1);
alert("Test 2 is...");
alert($("#test2 .three").prevAll().length == 1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($(this).prev(':first-child').length > 0) {
```